# Button Click not working in Vuforia AR camera unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have attached a script to Vuforia AR camera component inorder to add buttons to Ar camera surface .

```
void OnGUI()
{
    if (showComponent)
    {
        bool isOverlayClicked;
        int onePartHeight = Screen.width / 10;
        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height));  // x,y,w,h
        GUI.backgroundColor = Color.clear;
        isOverlayClicked=  GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, (Screen.height / 2) + 100 + (onePartHeight * 2)), "");
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, (Screen.height / 2) + 100 + (onePartHeight * 2)), btntexture);
        thisMenu.blocksRaycasts = thisMenu.interactable = false;//disallows clicks
        thisMenu.alpha = 0;   //makes menu invisible
        if (isOverlayClicked)
        {
            Debug.Log("Overlay clicked in unity");
        }
        GUILayout.EndArea();  

        bool isProfileButtonClicked;
        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect((Screen.width) - (iconSize + (25 * DPinPixels)), iconSize - (30 * DPinPixels), iconSize, iconSize));
        GUI.backgroundColor = Color.clear;
        isProfileButtonClicked = GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, iconSize, iconSize), "");
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, iconSize, iconSize), profileViewTexture);
        if (isProfileButtonClicked)
        {
            Debug.Log("Profile icon clicked in unity");
            openProfileActivity();
        }
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
}
```

Overlay Image click is always being called whenever I clicks the profile image.

To your note:
Overlay Image fills the entire screen.

I am attaching the screenshot of my app here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: I guess with `not working` you mean the overlay click is called though you only want the profile button click to be executed?

Answer (score 0):

In general I strongly recommend to not use `OnGUI` but rather the [Unity.Ui](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html)!

---

However, you could e.g. separate the GUI drawing and the setting of the bools from the executions of the reaction code:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    if (showComponent)
    {

        // First only draw the GUI and set the bools

        bool isOverlayClicked;
        int onePartHeight = Screen.width / 10;
        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height));  // x,y,w,h
        GUI.backgroundColor = Color.clear;
        isOverlayClicked=  GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, (Screen.height / 2) + 100 + (onePartHeight * 2)), "");
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, (Screen.height / 2) + 100 + (onePartHeight * 2)), btntexture);
        thisMenu.blocksRaycasts = thisMenu.interactable = false;//disallows clicks
        thisMenu.alpha = 0;   //makes menu invisible
        GUILayout.EndArea();  

        bool isProfileButtonClicked;
        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect((Screen.width) - (iconSize + (25 * DPinPixels)), iconSize - (30 * DPinPixels), iconSize, iconSize));
        GUI.backgroundColor = Color.clear;
        isProfileButtonClicked = GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, iconSize, iconSize), "");
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, iconSize, iconSize), profileViewTexture);
        GUILayout.EndArea();


        // Than later only react to the bools
        if (isProfileButtonClicked)
        {
            Debug.Log("Profile icon clicked in unity");
            openProfileActivity();

            // Return so nothing else is executed
            return;
        }

        // This is only reached if the other button was not clicked
        if (isOverlayClicked)
        {
            Debug.Log("Overlay clicked in unity");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

Finally i solved it using

> GUI.BeginGroup attribute.

I added the profile button as a child to the overlay image.

Also created a Fake button above the Rect which is used for click trigger. The code goes like this

```
    Rect overlayRect = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
                GUI.BeginGroup(overlayRect);  // x,y,w,h
                GUI.DrawTexture(overlayRect, btntexture);

                Rect profileRect = new Rect((Screen.width) - (iconSize + (5 * DPinPixels)), 10, iconSize, iconSize);
                GUI.DrawTexture(profileRect, profileViewTexture);


if (GUI.Button(profileRect, "", new GUIStyle()))
            {
                openProfileActivity();
            }
```